# WCF System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException

Tags: wcf-security

I am getting the following error message when trying to call my service from another server.

```
Service cannot be started.
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException:
The caller was not authenticated by the service. --->
System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
```

in my Event Viewer when I tried to connect the client to the server.

I enabled tracing in the server and it looks like the

`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException` is being thrown. The message says "The service does not allow you to log on anonymously."

I checked IIS -> WCF website and I do have the "Enable anonymous access" enabled.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Is another security setting enabled besides the anonymous?

If you have anonymous selected and another, and have basic or some other type selected you will run into this issue.  With WCF you are pretty much limited, while hosting in IIS, to a single security authentication model.

If you could elaborate a little bit I could possibly provide a better answer.  :)